# What is preventing me to run a specific application as administrator?

Tags: microsoft, runas

When I try to do it with the program I need to use this method for, it fails:

```
runas /user:%computername%\administrator "c:\Program Files (x86)\CountMeIn\Monitor.exe"
Enter the password for PC1\administrator:
Attempting to start c:\Program Files (x86)\CountMeIn\Monitor.exe as user "PC1\administrator" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - c:\Program Files (x86)\CountMeIn\Monitor.exe
740: The requested operation requires elevation.
```

Trying to debug this process, i test with a different application, and it works fine.
What could the problem be?

```
runas /user:%computername%\administrator "c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
Enter the password for PC1\administrator:
Attempting to start c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe as user "PC1\administrator" ...
```

Comment: See the Powershell response here: https://superuser.com/a/812902/31845

Answer (score 2):

You need to elevate your command prompt as administrator (Run as Administrator)

With PowerShell it's easier to elevate

```
$username = "YourUsername"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "YourPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path\To\Your\Program.exe" -Credential $credentials -Verb RunAs
```

-Verb runAs will elevate it

Comment: Just as a touch of clarification: "Administrator" as a user is not Administrator; that user is a member of the Administrators group, who run ordinarily with (reasonably high) User permissions but can elevate themselves on demand. Turdie's command set here is doing that elevation.

Comment: about that: I was using an elevated command prompt to try running this, originally. I'll try the powershell, thanks

Comment: I tried this, and the part that breaks it is '-Verb RunAs' --> Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.  CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException. The closest thing to -verb that the ISE want's to fill in is -verbose

Comment: The ISE is so outdated and is legacy, no wonder that it breaks, please use vscode(visual studio code) and the latest PowerShell version